# Reference problems with UITest in xamarin.droid

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set up UITest in the droid test project of our xamarin forms app. Everything works fine on the test project I made, but whenever I try to run tests on the real project, I get an exception while loading assemblies. The full error message is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() (Tests.Droid)
```

I've been working on this for several hours now without progress. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: What have you tried to fix it so far? It'll by then be easier to provide an answer different to what you've already tried yourself.

Comment: I've tried upgrading/downgrading Xamarin, nunit, UITest, and mvvmcross. I've tried every combination of "fast deployment", "use shared runtimes", and other build options. I've tried removing any dll's that reference System.Runtime.Remoting and System.Windows.Forms (won't work because UITest requires System.Windows.Forms). I've tried all of this in Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio.

Comment: Have you possibly tried to delete your Xamarin.Forms NuGet package? It seems to be the current working solution which is [how others got it to work again](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39338/xamarin-uitest-could-not-load-assembly-system-runtime-remoting).

Comment: Yes I've tried that in the test.droid project, the test.portable project, and the startup project with no luck

Comment: Could you try creating a new UITest project in Xamarin Studio and check if that works? Others have reported that doing so helped them.

If that doesn't help you either, I'm out of ideas, unfortunately. I'd then write their support channel if I were in your position.

Comment: I did (using the xamarin credit card project in their UITest tutorial) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a viable solution, then? To simply create a new UITest project in Xamarin Studio, that is?

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this problem. I have still got it

Comment: I did. Probably not the best way to do things, but I added the creditcardvalidator uitest project to my solution, deleted all the tests, and wrote my own.

Answer (score 0):

> **Xamarin.Android** does not support `System.Runtime.Remoting.dll`.

You will need to remove the use of that assembly.

**Refer :** [**Assemblies shipped by Xamarin**](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/assemblies/)

Use [**scan.xamarin.com**](https://scan.xamarin.com/) to determine if a particular assembly will work with **Xamarin.Android**.